# PowerShell form not displaying when screen is locked

Tags: forms, powershell, locking, screen, display

I'm using a PowerShell form to prompt users to close down Adobe Reader so it can be upgraded. It's executed via SCCM, so runs in the System context. It works if the user is logged on and the session is active, but if the screen is locked, the form does not display when I unlock the screen, although the script is running.

I originally used `$Form.ShowDialog()` to display it but saw some other posts that said it wasn't reliable, so I switched to `[void][System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Run($Form)` but it still doesn't work. Can anyone help me fix this please?

Below is the trimmed-down script with only the code relevant to rendering the form.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms, System.Drawing
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Segoe UI Light',14,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
$FontBold = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Segoe UI',13,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)

Function EndForm
{
    $Timer.Stop();
    $Timer.Dispose();
    $Label.Dispose();
    $CountdownLabel.Dispose();
    $ProgressBar.Dispose();
    $OKButton.Dispose();
    $Form.Close();
    $Form.Dispose();
}

$OnOKClick =
{
    $MsgBoxInput = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Are you sure you want to close and uninstall Adobe Reader now?","Confirm Adobe Reader Removal","YesNo","Warning")
    If ($MsgBoxInput -eq "Yes") {EndForm}
}

$Script:Countdown = 3600
$OKToolTip = "Click OK to close and uninstall Adobe Reader now"
$CountdownSubtitle = "Adobe Reader will close and uninstall in"

$Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label.AutoSize = $False
$Label.Height = 120
$Label.Width = 630
$Label.Font = $Font
$Label.BackColor = "White"
$Label.ForeColor = "#4D4C5C"
$Label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(52,180)
$Label.Text = "Your computer will soon be upgraded to newer versions of Windows 10 and Office 365. In order to succeed, the upgrade process requires that Adobe Reader be closed and uninstalled first. It will not be available for use again until after the upgrade has completed."

$CountdownLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$CountdownLabel.AutoSize = $False
$CountdownLabel.Height = 40
$CountdownLabel.Width = 530
$CountdownLabel.Font = $Font
$CountdownLabel.BackColor = "White"
$CountdownLabel.ForeColor = "#4D4C5C"
$CountdownLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,380)

$ProgressBar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
$ProgressBar.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(52,340)
$ProgressBar.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(635,35)
$ProgressBar.Style = "Continuous"
$ProgressBar.Maximum = $Script:Countdown
$ProgressBar.Minimum = 0

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Name = "OK_Button"
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,40)
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(330,450)
$OKButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$OKButton.Add_Click($OnOKClick)

$ToolTip = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip
$ToolTip.IsBalloon = $False 
$ToolTip.InitialDelay = 100 
$ToolTip.ReshowDelay = 200 
$ToolTip.SetToolTip($OKButton,$OKToolTip) 

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "Contoso LLC"
$Form.Font = $Font
$Form.Width = 770
$Form.Height = 580
$Form.MinimizeBox = $False
$Form.MaximizeBox = $False
$Form.ControlBox = $False
$Form.ShowIcon = $False
$Form.WindowState = "Normal"
$Form.FormBorderStyle = "Fixed3D"
$Form.ShowInTaskbar = $True
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Form.Topmost = $True
$Form.Controls.Add($ProgressBar)
$Form.Controls.Add($Label)
$Form.Controls.Add($CountdownLabel)
$Form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$Timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
$Timer.Interval = 1000
$Timer.Add_Tick(
{
    If ($Script:Countdown -eq 0) {EndForm}

    $ProgressBar.Value  = $Script:Countdown
    $TimeRemain = New-Timespan -Seconds $Script:Countdown
    $HrsRemain = $TimeRemain.Hours
    $MinsRemain = $TimeRemain.Minutes
    $SecsRemain = $TimeRemain.Seconds

    If ($HrsRemain -ge 2) {$HrsText = "$HrsRemain hours"}
    If ($HrsRemain -eq 1) {$HrsText = "$HrsRemain hour"}
    If ($MinsRemain -ge 2) {$MinsText = "$MinsRemain minutes"}
    If ($MinsRemain -eq 1) {$MinsText = "$MinsRemain minute"}
    If ($SecsRemain -ge 2) {$SecsText = "$SecsRemain seconds"}
    If ($SecsRemain -eq 1) {$SecsText = "$SecsRemain second"}

    $CountdownLabel.Text  = "$CountdownSubtitle $HrsText $MinsText $SecsText"

    If ($HrsRemain -ge 1 -And $MinsRemain -eq 0) {$CountdownLabel.Text = "$CountdownSubtitle $HrsText $SecsText"}
    If ($HrsRemain -eq 0) {$CountdownLabel.Text = "$CountdownSubtitle $MinsText $SecsText"}
    If ($HrsRemain -eq 0 -And $MinsRemain -eq 0) {$CountdownLabel.Text = "$CountdownSubtitle $SecsText"}
    $Script:Countdown--
})

$Timer.Start()
[void][System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Run($Form)
```

Comment: Hi, I never said I wanted the form to display over the top of a lock screen. I'm happy for it to run in the background while the screen is locked. This is just in case the user is away from their desk when the form appears, and they happen to unlock their screen before the countdown ends. In that case, if they are using Adobe Reader, it will stop without warning, which while not the end of the world, could possibly generate helpdesk incidents which is not ideal. I'd rather not argue the logic of why I'm doing it this way, I'd prefer to focus on coming up with a solution. Thanks.

Comment: As for needing to be logged on as the user, that is not correct. This form displays perfectly when deployed via SCCM, which as I said runs in the System context (although there is an option to run it in the user's context - which I have not set).

Comment: OK, deleted the other comments with this clarification, but you are sending a GUI to a currently logged on user. So, it must be in the user's context to see it. PowerShell only runs/outputs to the user context that started it.

Comment: I actually think I may have figured a way 'around' it by considering a locked screen the same as a logged off user, and so just end Adobe Reader in that case. Using the logonui process as the determining factor. I'll test it and see if that helps. Sure, it's not ideal but it could work - at least Adobe Reader won't close before their eyes and they'll wonder what happened.

Comment: Good deal, and if the SCCM approach was a catch22, my next suggestion would have been using the logonui check via a scheduled task and fire the script to pop the UI when the user screen is unlocked. Yep, if they are just reading a PDF< no harm/no foul, but if they are editing on, well, you know. Well, if they are editing PDF's via Word, vs Adobe, still no harm, no foul.

Comment: Yep, thanks for your suggestions anyway. It was good to bounce some ideas off you :)

Comment: Roger that, good luck, take care...

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to 'work around' this issue by detecting for the presence of the logonui process, which means the screen is locked. In that case, I will just close Adobe Reader anyway.